# Maven resources plugin filtering properties file with multiline value

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am using the Maven resources plugin to insert lines of code into a specific file. There are several lines of code so I need multiline support. This is only working, if I add those lines to the pom directly inbetween my properties tag and use

```
${line.separator}
```

However, I want my content inside a properties file. And if I use the "\" for the line breaks, the inserted code is written in one single line nevertheless.
Does anyone know how to achieve line breaks when using the filtering of the resources plugin with a properties file?